# multilevel constructors in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Okay we had the Task to create a constructer for a class which inherits from another, which also inherits from another class. Our solution to this was the following code:

```
AxeThrowerTroll:: AxeThrowerTroll(std::string name, char team, int health, unsigned int power, unsigned int armor, unsigned int numAxes)
: Troll(Monster(name, team, health, power), armor(armor)), numAxes(numAxes)
{
}
```

But if we want to compile the code we get the following error:

```
error: 'armor' cannot be used as a function
```

The definition of Troll is:

```
class Troll : public Monster
{
public:
    unsigned int armor;

    Troll(std::string, char, int, unsigned int, unsigned int);
    virtual void attack(Monster*);
    virtual void support(Monster*);
    virtual std::string asString();
};
```

Monster:

```
class Monster{

public:
    std::string name ;
    char team;
    int health;
    unsigned int power;

    Monster(std::string, char, int, unsigned int);
    virtual ~Monster();
    virtual void attack(Monster*);
    virtual void support(Monster*);
    virtual std::string asString();

};
```

Does one of you have a suggestion how we get this to work?

Comment: We're missing the definition of `Troll`. Please read [mcve] to help improve your question.

Comment: we're missing the definition of `AxeThrowerTroll`. It's not clear if your code `armor(armor)` is trying to set a member `armor` defined in `AxeThrowerTroll`, or if you imagine to set `Troll`'s member that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `AxeThrowerTroll::AxeThrowerTroll` definition should look like this:

```
AxeThrowerTroll::AxeThrowerTroll(std::string _name, 
                                 char _team, 
                                 int _health, 
                                 unsigned int _power,
                                 unsigned int _armor, 
                                 unsigned int _numAxes)
: Troll(_name, _team, _health, _power), armor(_armor)
```

`Troll`'s C'tor should be passed the arguments as is, as that what it signature requires, and you shouldn't have built a `Monster` instance for it (it's `Troll`'s responsibility).

Another thing - `Troll` doesn't have a `numAxes` data-member declared (according to your code). Once it does - add it to your initialization list.

Generally: all the arguments in the C'tor decleration shouldn't shadow data-members (that's why I added underscores - "_" - before each one). And each C'tor should only call the immediate base class C'tor and data-members in its initialization list.

Comment: It's normal practice to use the same name for constructor arguments as for the members they will initialize